# Ubuntu adding command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have php installed along with XAMPP. I can run php cli by typing **/opt/lampp/bin/php -arguments-here**, but I understand there must be a way to register a proper short command **php -arguments-here** ?

Edit:
I edited .bash_profile as per answer below, but I still keep getting the error:

*The program 'php' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install php5-cli*

Answer (score 0):

Put `/opt/lampp/bin` in your path.

Add the following lines to your `.bash_profile` (assuming you have a bash shell):

```
PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Comment: you just rephrased my question :) How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After doing what BetaRide suggested, you can make the change happen in your current shell session by executing:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Now, the environment variable $PATH has the value you just assigned to it.

Comment: still nothing :( the same error about php5-cli being not installed...

Comment: do: "echo $PATH" in the shell, you should have a "/opt/lampp/bin/" within it, do you?